# Having issue during web srapping due to same tags class names

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a school project for that i need to scrap doctor info to make recommendation model. The problem that i am facing is that doctors in website have multiple service locations and their tags have same class name. I just want one location for every doctor but i am getting all the location.

web link = https://oladoc.com/pakistan/lahore/gynecologist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctIx3.png) SS for the service locations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAZ0l.png) tages SS

here is the code SS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Tkh.png) Code SS

I tried multiple time but can't get just one location for doctor. The scrap text in append to list and then added to df

Comment: What location do you want? There are multiple locations

Comment: there are three location and for some there are multiple. One location like Hameed Latif Hospital (New Garden Town) will work. just don't want  Online Video Consultation (Online)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all doctors and then select all their hospitals (not containing string `"Online Video Consultaion"`):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://oladoc.com/pakistan/lahore/gynecologist"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for g in soup.select(".gynecologist"):
    print("Name:", g.h2.get_text(strip=True))

    hospitals = g.select(
        ".listing-locations:not(:-soup-contains('Online Video Consultation'))"
    )

    print("Hospitals:", [h.span.text for h in hospitals])
```

Prints:

```
Name: Dr. Ayesha Azam Khan
Hospitals: ['National Hospital & Medical Centre  (DHA)', 'Surgimed Hospital (Gulberg)']
Name: Dr. Maliha Amjad
Hospitals: ['Omar Hospital & Cardiac Centre (Johar Town) (Johar Town)', 'Shalamar Hospital (Mughalpura)']
Name: Dr. Sara Rasul
Hospitals: ['Hameed Latif Hospital (New Garden Town)', 'Hameed Latif Medical Center (DHA)']
Name: Dr. Sadia Sarwar
Hospitals: ['Evercare Hospital  (NESPAK Society)', 'Saira Memorial Hospital (Model Town)']
Name: Dr. Neena Jamil
Hospitals: ['Ammar Medical Complex (Jail Road)']
Name: Dr. Tanzeela Rehman
Hospitals: ['Omar Hospital & Cardiac Centre (Johar Town) (Johar Town)']
Name: Assist. Prof. Dr. Wajiha Rizwan
Hospitals: ['DHA Medical Centre (Lahore) (DHA)', 'Aadil Hospital (DHA) (DHA)', 'AMC Medical Center ']
Name: Lt. Col. (R) Dr. Ghazala Ishtiaq
Hospitals: ['Family Health Hospital (Johar Town)', 'Iqra Medical Complex (Johar Town)']
Name: Dr. Sania Awais
Hospitals: ['Horizon Hospital  (Johar Town)', 'Kishwar Sultana Hospital (Township)', 'Iffat Anwar Medical Complex (Township)', 'Fatima Memorial Hospital (Shadman)']
Name: Dr. Maria Azad
Hospitals: ['Hameed Latif Hospital (New Garden Town)', 'Cairns Railway Hospital (Near Railway Station)']
```

Comment: Thank very much for this. I just want to ask a question that can we get hospital names in the same order as in website or we can have only in this way ?. If you can clear this for me it would be great help and thank again for helping me out.

Comment: @YahyaKhalid What do you mean in same order? The hospitals are now listed in same order as under each doctor.

Comment: I meant that like in the website Dr. Maria Azad is showing on top  and Dr. Faiza Iqbal is second and so on. The order of doctors names and hospitals in the output is not same as in the website. Just want to know if it is possible to get the same order or the output will be in random order.

Comment: @YahyaKhalid You can probably use their pagination Ajax API (open Web Developer Tools -> Network tab and click on Load More Doctors, you should see the URL there)

Answer (score 0):

Use `soup.find` if you only need the first occurrence of that div or use indexes if you need a specific one.

Comment: If you want to use an index, you should use `soup.find_all(...)[index]`

Comment: Yeah, I mean, use an index with your existing code